# Spring cloud stream binder with Azure Eventhub

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am getting the below warning message in my boot application; what could be the issue ?

**The provided errorChannel 'x.y.errors' is an instance of DirectChannel, so no more subscribers could be added and no error messages will be sent to global error channel. Resolution: Configure your own errorChannel as an instance of PublishSubscribeChannel**

My config looks like this:

```
public interface CloudStreamConfig extends Source {

    String somethingIn = "somethingIn";
    String somethingOut= "somethingOut";
    String error= "topicname.some-service.errors";

    @Input(CloudStreamConfig.somethingIn)
    SubscribableChannel somethingIn();

    @Output(CloudStreamConfig.somethingOut)
    MessageChannel somethingOut();
}

Application yml:

cloud:
  azure:
    eventhub:
      connection-string: ${EVENTHUB_CONNECTION_STRING}
      checkpoint-storage-account: ${STORAGE}
      checkpoint-access-key: ${ACCESS_KEY}
  stream:
    bindings:
      somethingIn:
        destination: topic-name
        group: some-service
      somethingOut:
        destination: topic-name
        group: some-service
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best guess is you have a `@ServiceActivator` consuming from the binding's error channel.

If so, you need to explicitly define that channel as a `PublishSubscribeChannel` `@Bean` if you also want errors sent to the global error channel as well; if not, you can ignore that message.